# Ingress Nginx 502 Bad Gateway on Kubernates

Tags: nginx

Service-1:

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
name: hello-v1-svc
spec:
selector:
app: hello-v1
ports:

- protocol: TCP
  port: 80
  targetPort: 8080

Service-2:

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
name: hello-v2-svc
spec:
selector:
app: hello-v2
ports:

- protocol: TCP
  port: 80
  targetPort: 8080

Ingress:

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: ingress
annotations:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
ingressClassName: nginx
rules:

- host: v1.peladonerd.local
  http:
  paths:

  - path: /
    pathType: Exact
    backend:
    service:
    name: hello-v1-svc
    port:
    number: 80
- host: v2.peladonerd.local
  http:
  paths:

  - path: /
    pathType: Exact
    backend:
    service:
    name: hello-v2-svc
    port:
    number: 80

I am configuring an ingress with nginx in a kubernetes cluster but when trying to access the backend it sends me a 502 Bad Gateway

I shared the manifests that I am using